# $T(C)=C$ for some circle C passing through $ z_{0}$. Prove that $T'(z_{0})$ is real.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $T$ is a mobius transformation with a fixed point $ z_{0}\in \Bbb C$ such that  $T(C)=C$  for some circle $C$ passing through  $z_{0}$. Prove that $T'(z_{0})$ is real.

What I have done is:
WLOG taking  $z_{0}\in S^1$ 
Now the only possible Mobius map will be $T(z)=\frac1z$.
Hence $ T'(z)= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{T(z+h)-T(z)}{h}
=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{z+h}-\frac1z}{h}= \frac{-1}{z^2}\notin\Bbb R$.
So how to do it?

Comment: There are more Möbius transformations mapping the unit circle to itself. The thing to prove is not that $T'(z)\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $z$ (or only for all $z\in C$), but only that $T'(z_0)\in\mathbb{R}$. The fact that $z_0$ is a fixed point of $T$ is not unimportant.

Comment: What does $T'$ to the tangent to the circle through $z_0$?

Comment: The inversion fixed all points of the circle is'nt it?

Comment: Sorry I can't get your point. "What does $T′(z_{0})$ to the tangent to the circle through $z_{0}$?" means what?

Comment: The inversion doesn't fix all points of the unit circle. On the unit circle, it is the reflection in the real axis, it fixes only $1$ and $-1$. Take a differentiable curve $\gamma \colon (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) \to C$ with $\gamma(0) = z_0$. What is $(T\circ\gamma)'(0)$?

Comment: Yeah u r right.

Comment: $ T'(z_{0})\gamma'(0)$

Comment: What is $(T\circ\gamma)'(0)$ _geometrically_?

Comment: I think $(z\mapsto \bar z )$ is the reflection in the real axis.

Comment: Yes, but _on the unit circle_, that map is the same as the inversion. Since $$\frac{1}{z} = \frac{\overline{z}}{\lvert z\rvert^2},$$ and if the modulus is $1$, the right hand side simplifies to $\overline{z}$.

Comment: Ok. And I can't see the geometry. Help me on that

Comment: What is $T\circ\gamma$?

Comment: Don't know exactly. May be some nbd of $z_{0}$. Because T is continuous & fixes $z_{0}$.

Comment: $\gamma$ is a differentiable curve on $C$ with $\gamma(0) = z_0$. So $T\circ\gamma$ is ...?

Comment: Differentiable. Else what?

Comment: A differentiable curve ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17269/discussion-between-user152715-and-daniel-fischer).

Comment: Ok then? What about my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more or less obvious: One has $T'(z_0)=|T'(z_0)|\>e^{i\alpha}$, where $\alpha\in[0,2\pi[\ $ denotes the angle by which all tangent vectors attached at $z_0$ are turned under $T$ (resp., $dT$).  From $T(z_0)=z_0$ and $T(C)=C$ it follows that this angle is $=0$ or $=\pi$, so that $T'(z_0)$ is necessarily real.

Comment: ,How to prove "this angle is =0 or =π mod2π"??

I am getting the point geometrically but how to prove it explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. check my answer.
WLOG taking  $z_{0}\in S^1$ 
Now the only possible Mobius map will be $T(z)=\frac1z$.
Hence $ T'(z)= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{T(z+h)-T(z)}{h}
=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{z+h}-\frac1z}{h}= \frac{-1}{z^2}$.
Now T fixes only $\pm 1$ hence $ T'(z_{0})\in \Bbb R$.

Now for arbitrary cicle of radius r. The map will be $T(z)=\frac{r}{z-z_{0}}$. Here T will fix  $ (z_{0}\pm 1)$ & $ T'(z_{0}\pm 1)\in \Bbb R$ follows from my calculation in $S^1$.

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer will u please check it?